# Maya Legacy Viewport modelViewMatrix not updating properly

Tags: python, opengl, viewport, maya, legacy

I'm running into an issue when trying to grab a modelViewMatrix using maya's python OpenMayaUI and M3dView class. If you set your view to the legacy viewport (vp1), then query a modelViewMatrix after moving a camera using the cmds module it won't update. This same behavior works fine in Viewport 2.0 as well as High Quality Renderer.

Code example:

```
from maya import cmds
from maya import OpenMaya
from maya import OpenMayaUI


def do_this():
    """
    Get the current view and print it's modelViewMatrix.
    Then move it.
    """
    print('Doing this:')
    activeView = OpenMayaUI.M3dView.active3dView()

    cameraDagPath = OpenMaya.MDagPath()
    activeView.getCamera(cameraDagPath)
    cameraDagPath.pop()

    modelView_MMatrix = OpenMaya.MMatrix()
    activeView.modelViewMatrix(modelView_MMatrix)

    for column in xrange(0, 4):
        print(round(modelView_MMatrix(column, 0), 5),
              round(modelView_MMatrix(column, 1), 5),
              round(modelView_MMatrix(column, 2), 5),
              round(modelView_MMatrix(column, 3), 5))

    cmds.xform(
        cameraDagPath.fullPathName(),
        translation=[0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
        relative=True)
    cmds.xform(
        cameraDagPath.fullPathName(),
        rotation=[0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
        relative=True)

    cmds.refresh()


def do_that():
    """
    Get the current view and print it's modelViewMatrix.
    """
    print('Doing that:')
    activeView = OpenMayaUI.M3dView.active3dView()

    cameraDagPath = OpenMaya.MDagPath()
    activeView.getCamera(cameraDagPath)
    cameraDagPath.pop()

    modelView_MMatrix = OpenMaya.MMatrix()
    activeView.modelViewMatrix(modelView_MMatrix)

    for column in xrange(0, 4):
        print(round(modelView_MMatrix(column, 0), 5),
              round(modelView_MMatrix(column, 1), 5),
              round(modelView_MMatrix(column, 2), 5),
              round(modelView_MMatrix(column, 3), 5))

do_this()
do_that()

Doing this:
(-0.9641, 0.10179, -0.24527, -0.0)
(0.0, 0.92362, 0.3833, -0.0)
(0.26556, 0.36954, -0.89046, -0.0)
(-1231.52977, -2128.24206, 3574.6381, 1.0)

Doing that:
(-0.9641, 0.10179, -0.24527, -0.0)
(0.0, 0.92362, 0.3833, -0.0)
(0.26556, 0.36954, -0.89046, -0.0)
(-1231.52977, -2128.24206, 3574.6381, 1.0)
```

How can I get this update properly? The only fix I've found is to select the viewport inbetween these two functions and it'll properly update. Is there a way to force refresh the modelViewMatrix in Maya? Appreciate any help!